# What drill and screws should I use to attach security bar to a concrete wall

Tags: concrete, drill, security

I have a few security bars to attach to my garage window. These are the bars:
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/291320181452?euid=37bd934e70374116905fb2a20e9f7fad&cp=1

I have the Face Fix Brackets. The brackets have 5mm holes in them.

There is concrete surrounding the window. I have tried drilling a hole with a hammer drill that my friend lent me (750w) and I used a masonry drill bit but it barely scratched the surface. I need to drill 16 holes so I need something better. Therefore, this is what I want to know:

I'm going to buy a drill, what would be best for this sort of job?
What would be the best way to attach the security bars so that they are so secure they couldn't just be kicked out. I don't think a wall plug would be that secure?

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: I have to ask - are you sure you moved the switch/slider/toggle/whatever on the drill to 'hammer' mode? If it didn't make a $@#*& awful noise when you put some pressure on it then probably not ...

Comment: I did indeed use the hammer setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had one of those drills with a hammer setting rather than an actual hammer drill then that would explain it.

Like [this](https://www.zoro.com/milwaukee-dual-speed-hammer-drill-kit-12-in-5387-22/i/G4937003/?gdffi=047ada998cf641fa93e55ae8579df863&gdfms=EAB4DE4B66674427B1F2790E70C2B6C3&gclid=Cj0KEQjwrte4BRD-oYi3y5_AhZ4BEiQAzIFxn4-__EYSCrgqhQuYhCCadVvydL6pQojjuyl-7_FCTVcaAmoE8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) one.

You need an SDS hammer drill like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003DQO7ES).

Before you buy one just for a small project, see if there is a place to rent one near you. In the US, Menard's rents tools for small projects. Most rental places have them. You may have to buy a drill bit.

Then use anchors like TapCons for concrete like [these](http://www.lowes.com/pd_79361-2191-24310_0__?productId=3043982).

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'll give it a go and report back.